# Button Width Adjusts to Width of Window (or containing div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I am building a mobile site and would like to have some buttons that span the entire width of the screen.

Here is the button:

```
<a class="btn" "href="http://www.myurl.com/">TEXXT</a>
```

And the CSS:

```
.btn {
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 6px 15px #666666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 6px 15px #666666;
  box-shadow: 1px 6px 15px #666666;
  font-family: "NimbusCondensed";
  font-size: 28px;
  background: #0088CB;
  padding: 20px 50px 20px 50px;
  border: solid #000000 1px;
  text-decoration: none; }
```

I would like the width of the button to adjust to the window in order to accommodate different mobile devices.

I have the containing div adjusting already so if I could set the button to the div width, that would work just as well.

Thank you!

Comment: Just saying, but your <a> tag has a syntax error, you have an extra `"` BEFORE `href`. `<a class="btn" href="http://www.myurl.com/">TEXXT</a>` <-- this is the correct syntax.

Comment: Position:relative;width:100%;

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mangesh/mdpx1w4s/)

```
.btn {
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 6px 15px #666666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 6px 15px #666666;
  box-shadow: 1px 6px 15px #666666;
  font-family: "NimbusCondensed";
  font-size: 28px;
  background: #0088CB;
  padding: 20px 50px 20px 50px;
  border: solid #000000 1px;
  text-decoration: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [sizing with CSS3's vw units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length)

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0}  /*Reset style*/
.btn {
  width: 100vw;   /*width of the viewport*/
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 6px 15px #666666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 6px 15px #666666;
  box-shadow: 1px 6px 15px #666666;
  font-family: "NimbusCondensed";
  font-size: 28px;
  background: #0088CB;
  padding: 20px 50px 20px 50px;
  border: solid #000000 1px;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" "href="http://www.myurl.com/">TEXXT</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

anchor `<a>` tag is `display : inline;` by default, change it to `display : block;` so that it can take the parent width.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/3r96f8d8/)

```
.btn {
    display:block;   <---------------------- /* just add this */
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 6px 15px #666666;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 6px 15px #666666;
    box-shadow: 1px 6px 15px #666666;
    font-family:"NimbusCondensed";
    font-size: 28px;
    background: #0088CB;
    padding: 20px 50px 20px 50px;
    border: solid #000000 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at viewport-percentage [Viewport-percentage lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)

```
width: 100vw;
```

Answer (score 0):

For making an element the width of its container,

```
display: block;
width: auto;
```

is your friend.